# How can I find the maximum natural number representable by a given count of cubes with single digit natural numbers painted on the sides

Tags: set-theory

Backstory - I have a baby on the way and have come across a product that is wooden cubes with single digits painted on the side. They come in a set of three cubes and a units block, with the idea being that you can photograph your baby with them and arrange it such that it might say 20 days old, with a [2][0][days] block faces showing for example.

This got me wondering what approach I might take to understand how they might have decided which numbers to paint on which cubes, and if there is a way to calculate a maximum natural number that could be represented by N cubes.

I'm not really sure what category of mathematics it might even be, set theory maybe? I need to pick one tag so going with that as a guess

Comment: Congratulations on the baby.

Comment: Yes, congrats! By maximum natural number, you mean the largest value that can be shown continuously from $1$, right? By that I mean that if one cube can show numbers $1-6$ and $9$, but not $7$, is the largest one counted $6$ or $9$? If it's $9$, the answer is probably just $10^n-1$ for $n$ cubes 

Answer (score 2):

Note that we do not need to paint $9$, because $6$ can be turned upside-down.

Paint the cubes in the following three-cube cycle:
$\color{red}{123456}$
$\color{red}{780123}$
$\color{red}{456780}$
$\color{red}{123456}$
$\color{red}{780123}$
$\color{red}{456780}$
$\color{red}{123456}$
And so on.

I claim:

> The first $N$ cubes can express every integer from $1$ to $f(N)=(\text{$N$th decimal of $0.\overline{741}$})\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\lfloor2N/3\rfloor}10^k-1$.

For example:
$f(1)=6$
$f(2)=43$
$f(3)=110$
$f(4)=776$
$f(5)=4443$
$f(6)=11110$
$f(7)=77776$
$f(8)=444443$

(Testing my claim with the first few $N$ values should reveal a convincing pattern.)

Now I will show that $N$ cubes *cannot* be painted to express every integer from $1$ to $f(N)+1$.

First, a specific case (easier to follow). Assume, for the sake of contradiction, that $5$ cubes can be painted to express every integer from $\color{red}{1}$ to $\color{red}{4444}$. To express $\color{red}{111,222,333,\dots,999,1000}$, nine digits must appear at least three times (remember, $6$ can be turned upside-down to become $9$). To express $\color{red}{1111,2222,3333,4444}$, four digits must appear one more time. So we need $9\times 3 + 4=31$ digits, but we only have $5\times 6 =30$ faces. Contradiction. Therefore $5$ cubes cannot be painted to express every integer from $\color{red}{1}$ to $\color{red}{4444}$.

Now, the general case. Assume that $N$ cubes can be painted to express every integer from $\color{red}{1}$ to $\color{red}{f(N)+1}$. To express $\color{red}{1T_N,2T_N,\dots,9T_N, 9T_N+1}$, where $T_N=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{{\lfloor2N/3\rfloor}-1}10^k$, nine digits must appear at least $\lfloor2N/3\rfloor$ times. To express $\color{red}{1S_N,\dots,u_NS_N}$, where $S_N=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\lfloor2N/3\rfloor}10^k$ and $u_N=\text{$N$th decimal of $0.\overline{741}$}$, $u_N$ digits must appear one more time. So we need $9\times \lfloor2N/3\rfloor+u_N$ digits, but we only have $6\times N$ faces. It can be shown that  $9\times \lfloor2N/3\rfloor+u_N>6\times N$ for all $N\in\mathbb{N}$ (for example, consider $N\mod{3}$). Contradiction. Therefore $N$ cubes cannot be painted to express every integer from $\color{red}{1}$ to $\color{red}{f(N)+1}$.